# SQLLDR and NULL Field detection in column to be imported

Tags: database, oracle, csv, import, sql-loader

SQLLDR and CTL file

Got a CSV file to import.

I want to specify in my CTL file to insert only into my table when I've got an empty value in a certain column in my CSV file. E.G  I want to upload only user's records who **don't** have a termination date.

I've tried various options

- When TERMINATIONDATE = ''
- When TERMINATIONDATE = ""
- When TERMINATIONDATE = null
- When TERMINATIONDATE = 'null'

It only works when I'm using

- When TERMINATIONDATE != ''
  then i get all my employees that have been terminated.
  But i want the opposite...

Doesn't look like it's possible after all?

my CTL file

```
OPTIONS (SKIP=1)
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'C:\temp\users.csv' 
BADFILE 'C:\temp\users.bad'
DISCARDFILE 'C:\temp\users.dsc'
TRUNCATE
INTO TABLE "alawakaba"."users"
When TERMINATIONDATE = ''
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
ID,
FIRSTNAME,
LASTNAME,
FUNCTION,
DEPARTMENT,
COSTCENTER,
HIREDATE,
Field8 FILLER,
TERMINATIONDATE,
LOCCODE
)
```

(Column8 is just one I don't need so I'm skipping that)

Answer (score 1):

It should work with the following clause:

```
WHEN TERMINATIONDATE = BLANKS
```

Comment: didn't do the trick :(  It just ignores all of them . Somehow SQLLDR can not use the When with blanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not the ultimate solution and has some overhead but I can do it in 2 runs:

a) Run as CTL above.
Change the 
*When TERMINATIONDATE = ''*
to 
**When TERMINATIONDATE != ''**

The  discarded records will be injected into the **DISCARDFILE 'C:\temp\users.dsc'**
now my discarded file will contain all the records i wanted to upload

b) Run a second CTL command to pickup the DSC file as input, don't skip records anymore and don't specify the when clause neither

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'C:\temp\users.dsc' 
BADFILE 'C:\temp\users.bad'
DISCARDFILE 'C:\temp\users-run2.dsc'
TRUNCATE
INTO TABLE "alawakaba"."users"
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
ID,
FIRSTNAME,
LASTNAME,
FUNCTION,
DEPARTMENT,
COSTCENTER,
HIREDATE,
Field8 FILLER,
TERMINATIONDATE,
LOCCODE
)
```

Not the best or quickest one around but it does the trick.

Can't believe that such a simple clause is not working from the start in SQLLDR.